# How do i authenticate my api (node app) when being accessed by my UI?

Tags: node.js, authentication, api-key

I've looked at various approaches to this but I'm yet to find one that is perfect for my set up.

I have a UI that calls the api to present data to a user - the UI doesn't require someone to login and i don't want to authenticate every user. What i'm trying to do is simply protect the api because with the url to the api, anyone will be able to access the data.

In my mind, i can create a password/ apikey of some sort and store that as an environment variable that is sent from the UI to the API whenever a request is made. On the API, that apikey/password is validated before allowing access to the api.

Does this sound wise? Would you suggest something else? Have i missed anything. All thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The solution sounds good to me. You can do something like this:

- **back-end**: create a new REST endpoint (something like `/api/get-token`) in your Node.JS application which generates a token (or ID), saves it locally (maybe into a DBMS) and returns it as response. Then, in every endpoint you need to protect, you extract the token from the request and, before sending any "private" data, you check if the supplied token is valid, or not.
- **front-end**: as soon as your application is loaded, you send a request to the newly created REST endpoint and store the given token locally (`localStorage` should be fine). Then, every time the UI needs to access "private" data, you simply supply the claim within the request.

The implementation should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for this ! I've read in a few places that storing it in `localStorage` isn't a good idea - why do think it'll be okay in this case?

Comment: The main reason why localStorage is usually avoided is because it's synchronous, but for small things like this should be more than fine.

Comment: I'll follow half your implementation but that's not what i've read re localStorage - have a read here https://www.rdegges.com/2018/please-stop-using-local-storage/#psa-don-t-store-json-web-tokens-in-local-storage

Comment: additionally, what happens when my token expires?

Comment: Token expiration is out of the scope of this thread. Anyway, happy to be helpful.